# Portably testing for the POPCNT instruction

Tags: config, sse, configure, autoconf, cpu-architecture

I'd like my configure script to detect the availability of the POPCNT instruction across a wide variety of Unix-like systems.  At the moment I do these tests:

1. Look for "popcnt" in /proc/cpuinfo.  This works in Linux and Cygwin.
2. Look for "popcnt" in the output of "sysctl -n machdep.cpu.features". This works in MACOSX and (untested) BSD,
3. Look for "popcnt" in the output of "isainfo -v -x". This works (untested) in solaris.

The greps are done case-independently. Can you see any problems with these, and do you know of any other tests?

Tests requiring root privilege are no use.

Comment: I suppose using something like the [cpuid](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html) command-line tool is out of the question :)

Comment: Do you generate POPCNT with a C/C++ intrinsic, inside inline assembly block, or from a standalone assembly file?

Comment: @rici : The cpuid tool is only for x86 systems as far as I can tell, and is not part of the default tool set for Ubuntu, for example.  I don't want to ask people to install anything.

Comment: @Marat : I use the __builtin_popcount series in gcc and the _mm_popcnt_u32 series in icc.

Answer (score 1):

So you have code that enables `-mpopcnt` and uses `__builtin_popcount` if that will be fast.  Otherwise you use something different, because your custom solution beats gcc's implementation?

Keep in mind that host != target in some cases.  Build-time CPU detection is not appropriate for making binaries that have to run on other machines.  e.g. Linux distros making binaries.  Cross-compiling for is also a thing, and is commonly done when targeting an embedded system or an old slow system.

---

Maybe write a custom C program that returns the result you want.

On x86, you could just use the result of runtime CPU detection: run the `CPUID` instruction and check if popcnt is supported.  It's probably best not to unconditionally run the `popcnt` instruction, since processes that run an illegal instruction generate a syslog entry on some modern distros (e.g. Ubuntu).

With recent GNU C extensions, the easiest way to do that is: `__builtin_cpu_init()` and `__builtin_cpu_supports("popcnt")`, saving you the trouble of manually decoding the CPUID results.

---

You could then fall back to a micro-benchmark of a `__builtin_popcount` against your custom macro, and take whichever is faster.  That might be useful even on non-x86 architectures where your macros beat gcc's implementation.  (e.g. an architecture that always has a popcnt instruction available).  Then you'd have to handle the case where you should use `__builtin_popcount` but not build with `-mpopcnt`